# Variable value loaded from parse.com, resets to 0 after function returns

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my fragment, I have declared the `food` variable

```
public class EatingFragment extends Fragment  {

...
static int food = 0;

}
```

I load the variable from a parse.com database.  Inside the `onCreateView()` function, I call the function `loadSwallowCount()`, implemented as below

```
void loadSwallowCount() {

        SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        String id = pref.getString("parse_object_id", "empty");
        if (id == "empty") {
            food = 0;
            Log.d("Not stored"," Swallow count not stored on device");
        }
        else {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserData");
            query.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject onlineData, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        food = onlineData.getInt("SwallowCount");
                        Log.d("mes", "food is " + food);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

When I test the food count inside the `loadSwallowCount` function, I get the proper value.  However, after the function returns to `onCreateView()`, I do another log, and strangely the value of `food` is 0.

Comment: How do you log the value in your fragment ? This function returns nothing, so what you see in onCreateView() may be the static int food.

Comment: the GetCallback is async, so maybe you reach the log in onCreateView before the GetCallback is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadSwallowCount` is a function that use the method call `getInBackground`, which has a asyncronous callback in `new GetCallback<ParseObject>`.

This means that your code reach your log in `onCreateView` before the callback is called.

In this case, you will be able to use your `food` variable only after the callback is executed.

try this:

```
public void done(ParseObject onlineData, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        food = onlineData.getInt("SwallowCount");
        processFoodValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of waiting until the value is set, or is this the best way?

Comment: Since this is a callback from async operation, I don't see better approach